# Unable to compare magic constant __METHOD__

Tags: php, class, magic-constants

Ok, I think I have something here...

Inside a class, im trying to condition a private function based on the used method's name.

So the code looks something like:

```
<?php
class my_class{

 public function my_method($arg1) {
  $this->private_function($arg1);
 }

 private function private_function($arg2){
  if (__METHOD__ == "my_class::my_method"){
    #THIS FAILS
  }else{
    #THIS WORKS
  }
  return;
 }
}

(new my_class())->my_method($something);
```

If I do a var_dump() on `__METHOD__` at the same level im trying to use it I'll get a nice `string(19)"my_class::my_method"`. So I'm comparing a string to another one.

The following will also fail:

- Cast both vars to string and compare them.
- Copy `__METHOD__` to a `(string) $var` and compare them.
- Upper both strings and compare them.
- Using single quotes for the text.

I might be wrong but I think I hit a bug here :(

**PHP Version 5.6.1 - Win**

Comment: I tried `$a = __METHOD__; echo $a === __METHOD__ ? 1 : 2;`, it prints `1`

Comment: `__METHOD__` should be `my_class::private_function`

Comment: I updated it to reflect the called method...

Comment: @Andrew, your aproach is comparing `__METHOD__` to itself... I need to compare `__METHOD__` against text values or vice versa.

Comment: @SolracRagnarockradio Total shot in the dark, but could you try enclosing the method name in single quotes instead of double?

Comment: @Daedalus I tryed it without any luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__METHOD__` returns the current class method name. In your case this is `my_class::private_function`.

If you want to know the caller method, the cleanest way is to pass it as argument.

```
class my_class {

    public function my_method($arg1) {
        $this->private_function($arg1, __METHOD__);
    }

    private function private_function($arg2, $caller) {
        if ($caller == "my_class::my_method") {

        } else {

        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my mind __METHOD__ had the value of the public function but I got it all wrong...

Thanks @chumkiu I think I need some sleep :P

Comment: would it be better to use `debug_backtrace` to get the caller method name ,so every time `private_function` is used, we dont need to add the second arg to the caller, and only need to focus on `private_function` ?? just my humble opinion

Comment: it's never a good idea to use a function with prefix `debug` in not development environment :). The cleaner way is to pass to the function all it need to do its work. It should be also more explicative of a function name by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the `__FUNCTION__`
I guess `__METHOD__` will return class name along with the function name.

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` will return `private_function` instead of the called method which is `my_class::my_method`